# Why can't I just differentiate directly in this IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the following problem:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} - 2xy = 2 \ \ \ \ y(0) = 1$$

I find that the integrating factor is:

$$\mu = e^{-x^2}$$

I am wondering why I can't differentiate directly here in the next step, like this:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(e^{-x^2}y)=2e^{-x^2}$$
$$y\frac{d}{dx}e^{-x^2} = 2e^{-x^2}$$
$$-2yxe^{-x^2} = 2e^{-x^2}$$

Which apparently is incorrect.

EDIT: It is because $y$ is a function of x...

Comment: You are correct. It is because $y$ depends on $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Since $y$ is a function of $x$ we have:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{-x^2}y \right)=-2xye^{-x^2}+e^{-x^2}\frac{dy}{dx}
$$
anyway you can integrate directly
$$
\int d\left(e^{-x^2}y \right)=\int 2e^{-x^2}dx
$$
using the [Error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)
$$
ye^{-x^2}=\sqrt{\pi} \mbox{ erf}(x)+C 
$$